# Verify from a local system if an Amazon EC2 instance is in use

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, remote-access, remote-desktop

We have a multiple Amazon EC2 instances(windows). How to find out the state of an instance i.e. if the instance is busy or is in idle state? 
Guess it might be possible via Powershell but i am not very sure on this as i dont know much of powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 instances send metrics to Amazon CloudWatch, including:

- CPU Utilization
- Disk access
- Network traffic

See documentation: [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud Dimensions and Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ec2-metricscollected.html)

This information can be retrieved from CloudWatch by using the [`get-metric-statistics`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html) API call or via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). An **alarm** can also be configured in CloudWatch to trigger a notification when a threshold is passed (eg below 10% CPU utlization for 15 minutes).

See documentation: [Creating Amazon CloudWatch Alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html)

If you wish to capture additional metrics, such as free disk space or free memory, you will can send log files to **CloudWatch Logs**.

See documentation: [Sending Performance Counters to CloudWatch and Logs to CloudWatch Logs Using Amazon EC2 Simple Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-configuration-cwl.html)